# Как реализовать функцию, которая возвращает новую строку, в которой каждое слово, которое содержит 5 или больше символов, написана наоборот?

Tags: javascript

надо реализовать функцию, которая принимает строку в качестве аргумента и возвращает новую строку, в которой каждое слово, которое содержит 5 или больше символов, написана наоборот,
пробовал

```js
const reverseLongWords = (str) => {
  let arr = str.split(" ");

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length >= 5) {
      arr[i] = arr[i].split("").reverse().join("");
    }
  }
  return arr;   
};
```

не сработало с массивом, как правильно реализовать?

Comment: "не сработало с массивом," --- что это значит?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, извиняюсь, неправильно выразился, при тесте "Hey wollef sroirraw" вернуло массивом ["Hey", "wollef", "sroirraw"]

Comment: ну ты возвращаешь массив.... верни join и всё

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, исправил на return arr.join(" "); сработало, спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Реализовать функцию которая принимает строку в качестве аргумента и возвращает новую строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1419692/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const reverseLongWords = (str) => {
  let arr = str.split(" ");

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length >= 5) {
      arr[i] = arr[i].split("").reverse().join("");
    }
  }
  return arr.join(" ");   
};
```